# Converting css to sass? Can't get keyframes to work

Tags: css, sass, gruntjs, css-animations

I've been trying to implement this codepen: https://codepen.io/paulrogers/pen/KWORqz
Specifically this piece:

```css
/*Horizontal Sliding*/
.slidingHorizontal{
 display: inline;
 text-indent: 8px;
}
.slidingHorizontal span{
 animation: leftToRight 12.5s linear infinite 0s;
 -ms-animation: leftToRight 12.5s linear infinite 0s;
 -webkit-animation: leftToRight 12.5s linear infinite 0s;
 color: #00abe9;
 opacity: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: absolute;
}
.slidingHorizontal span:nth-child(2){
 animation-delay: 2.5s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 2.5s;
 -webkit-animation-delay: 2.5s;
}
.slidingHorizontal span:nth-child(3){
 animation-delay: 5s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 5s;
 -webkit-animation-delay: 5s;
}
.slidingHorizontal span:nth-child(4){
 animation-delay: 7.5s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 7.5s;
 -webkit-animation-delay: 7.5s;
}
.slidingHorizontal span:nth-child(5){
 animation-delay: 10s;
 -ms-animation-delay: 10s;
 -webkit-animation-delay: 10s;
}





/*leftToRight Animation*/
@-moz-keyframes leftToRight{
 0% { opacity: 0; }
 5% { opacity: 0; -moz-transform: translateX(-50px); }
 10% { opacity: 1; -moz-transform: translateX(0px); }
 25% { opacity: 1; -moz-transform: translateX(0px); }
 30% { opacity: 0; -moz-transform: translateX(50px); }
 80% { opacity: 0; }
 100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes leftToRight{
 0% { opacity: 0; }
 5% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateX(-50px); }
 10% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateX(0px); }
 25% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateX(0px); }
 30% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateX(50px); }
 80% { opacity: 0; }
 100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@-ms-keyframes leftToRight{
 0% { opacity: 0; }
 5% { opacity: 0; -ms-transform: translateX(-50px); }
 10% { opacity: 1; -ms-transform: translateX(0px); }
 25% { opacity: 1; -ms-transform: translateX(0px); }
 30% { opacity: 0; -ms-transform: translateX(50px); }
 80% { opacity: 0; }
 100% { opacity: 0; }
}
```

I'm trying to integrate the css into my main.scss file -- I'm aware that the scss file doesn't recognize keyframes -- but I'm having trouble converting.

Any help would be appreciated! I'm very new to scss so any extra explanations would be awesome!

Comment: I'm converted to sass here `https://codepen.io/kenz/pen/mwdmrO` Are you can posted your sass code to preview problem

Comment: Thanks so much! Looks like this worked!